# Расстановка подлежащего и сказуемого

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология

Спорим на работе о разнице между: *Загружается список* или *список загружается* или *загрузка списка*.
Рассудите, если ли разница (не только между предложенными словосочетаниями, а вообще в расстановке подлежащего и сказуемого) и если есть, то какая.

Comment: В общем случае - стилистическая, не более. Но у вас же есть и третий вариант, там нет сказуемого, в чем вопрос тогда? А вообще приводите всю фразу целиком, не заставляйте отвечающего гадать на кофейной гуще. Контекст - наше всё.

Answer (score 1):

Разница есть, так как простое предложение делится на две части: **тема (предмет) и рема (сообщение о предмете.**

**1) Загружается список.** Предмет - это процесс загрузки, сообщение - в данный момент загружается (что?) список.

**2) Список загружается.** Предмет - список, сообщение - что  ним происходит,   он (что делает?) загружается.

**Загрузка списка** - это словосочетание, оно может входить в структуру предложения, может быть назывным предложением.

Стоит отметить, что **построение предложений по типу тема-рема постоянно присутствует в нашей речи**, при этом говорящий интуитивно может изменять порядок слов, из-за чего меняются смысловые  (но не стилистические) оттенки сообщения.

Comment: *Разница есть,* - между 1) и 2) ? Оригинально, оригинально...

Answer (score 1):

Разница есть. Важно то, что уже известно адресату.

1. Загружается список (что сейчас происходит). Выбор такого выражения соответствует случаю, когда **оба слова** для адресата **значимы**: он вряд ли без этого сообщения предполагает, какое действие и над чем производится. Менее вероятно, но возможно, что он ожидает загрузки чего-то разного и ему сообщают, что сейчас загружается именно список (а не напр. календарь).
2. Список загружается (~=брюки превращаются) - что происходит со списком. Это более уместно в случае, если адресат ожидает каких-то действий с уже *известным* ему "списком". Для него информативно то, **какое действие происходит** со списком или начался ли процесс его загрузки, которого он ожидал.
3. Загрузка списка (что). Само по себе это мало что значит (может использоваться как название кнопки для загрузки списка, заголовок к инструкции и т.п.). Если это используется как текущее сообщение, то оно может говорить адресату о происходящем в данный момент процессе или просто быть ответом на какой-то его вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что это текст в информационном окне загрузки списка.
Я бы написал "Список загружается" или "Загрузка списка". Либо, если у списка есть имя, то "Загружается список <имя>" или "Загрузка списка <имя>".

Answer (score 0):

Между нами? програмкрами: разницы никакой. 
Выбирать стоит лишь в ситуации, когда такое сообщение само по себе информативно.

Ну например, в наборе действий "список загружается" "список сортируется" "список обрабатывается" "список выгружается" - имеет смысл именно такой порядок

А для набора "Загружается список" "Загружается справочник" "Загружается запрос" - соответственно обратный предыдущему.

"Загрузка списка" - а это калька с английского герундия, лучше в подобной  ситуации не использовать вообще, оставить для статики и фраз типа "загрузка списка осуществляется с помощью модуля такого-то".

> Предмет - это процесс загрузки, сообщение - в данный момент загружается (что?) список.  -

Не сказал бы, что такой подход актуален для русского разговорного. Тема и рема определяется более всего грамматикой, потом - интонацией. И только в редких случаях - порядком слов. В любом случае к практической ситуации (если считать, что это надпись на экране во аремя работы приложения) это все малоприменимо. Ну какая, к шуту, пользователю разница, где там тема и рема, вопрос стоит, как доходчивее донести  до него, о чем программа задумалась.